# Temporarily disabling PIN/password lock on Android

Tags: java, android

Is thera a way to temporarily disable PIN or password lock on an Android device? `keyguardLock.disableKeyguard()` only works for swipe/pattern locks.

I'd prefer a solution for non-rooted phones, but if there isn't one then requiring root is ok.

Comment: What do you want to do?  Do you want to pop up your app on top of the lock?  Then yes.  If you want to turn off the lock, for other apps, then no-  and there shouldn't be.

Comment: I want to disable the lock completely, as Tasker does (with root). I realize it's a security concern, but still want to know how they do it.